# Drupal Form autocomplete

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, drupal-7

I wanted to have a textfield in a form that autocompletes from the database. I have been reading the tutorials and trying to get it to work but thus far not much luck. I am farely new to Drupal so I'm mostly unsure what I am doing xD

My code thus far:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['my_module/form'] = array(
    'title' => t('Add List'),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => t('My form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

// path with autocomplete function for casters
  $items['caster/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => t('Autocomplete for casters'),
    'page callback' => '_caster_autocomplete',
    'access arguments' => array('use autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_module_form() {
  return drupal_get_form('my_module_my_form');
}

function _caster_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();
  $results = db_select('warnoun', 'w')
    ->fields('w', array('full_name'))
    ->condition('full_name', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute();
  // save the query to matches
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $matches[$result->full_name] = check_plain($result->full_name);
  }
  // Return the result to the form in json
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}

function my_module_my_form($form_state) {
  $form['points'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Points'),
    '#required' => TRUE, // Added
    '#options' => array(
         0 => t('15'),
         1 => t('25'),
         2 => t('35'),
         3 => t('50'),
       ),
  );
  $form['caster'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Caster'),
    '#maxlength' => 50,
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'caster/autocomplete',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $entries = db_query('SELECT id, short_name FROM factions ORDER BY id ASC');
  $options = array();
  foreach ($entries as $entry){
        $options[$entry->id] = t($entry->short_name);
  }



  $form['faction'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => t('Faction'),
       '#options' => $options,
   );

   // Simple Submit Button
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#required' => TRUE, // Added
  );
  return $form;
}
```

So basically there is a table called *warnoun* with a column *full_name* and it's with that content that I want to autocomplete the textfield *caster*.

Any idea what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: You need to flush the cache after every change is done inside hook_menu() implementation. Try doing that, and see if it works.

Comment: Also see the output you are getting from visiting autocomplete url from your browser and append a string to search at the end of the url `caster/autocomplete/blah`.

Comment: Hey Muhammad, thx for the help. That wasn't the whole issue but at least now I got it working. I was testing on a different browser (Safari) so I could see how things looked while not logged in. Apparently that was an issue, while not logged in the autocomplete didn't work.I noticed it when I loaded the page in My Main browser and i just showed up.

Comment: Change this line `'access arguments' => array('use autocomplete'),` to be `'access arguments' => array('access content'),`. And then flush the caches.

Comment: This is baffling. I finally got it to work but I'm not 100% sure how. I did as you mentioned and changed the access arguments value but it wasn't working. I eventually found out that including `'access callback' => TRUE,` should grant permission to everyone so I did this and it seemed to fix the problem. However when I removed this line to make sure this was fixing the issue it kept on working xS so like I said I'm not 100% sure what the answer is...